# Vue.js : JS-Animation-Hooks with GSAP - leave animation not working

Tags: animation, vuejs2, gsap

I want to use **enter/leave transitions** in **vue.js**, using the built in javascript hooks for transitions:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks

My animation library of choice is **GSAP**: https://greensock.com/

Both, my enter function `enter: function(el, done) {}` and my leave function `leave: function(el, done) {}` are called correctly.

The enter animation works just fine — but the leave animation doesn't do anything.

I guess it is a GSAP related thing I do not understand yet. I tried resetting the animation and clearing the inline styles of the animated element. Didn't help.

Here is the codepen:
https://codepen.io/Sixl/pen/oGwOKW?editors=0011

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar problem but not identical. Discovered in my case it was use of v-if instead of v-show was causing the leave transition to fail -- switching to v-show fixed it. This is a little confusing as this isn't mentioned in the docs as far as I could see. (You'd think transitions work in most cases with v-if, too, but in my case it didn't - I was tweening one element directly as in your example (accessing it off of 'el'), another was a data property (accessed off of this.$data). That might be a reason for the failure to work with v-if, I'm not sure on this point at the moment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fixed version: https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/veJGmR?editors=0010

I noticed a few problems:

1. You were calling done() immediately instead of waiting for the animation to complete. I just moved it to an onComplete callback.
2. You created a single timeline that you were adding all your animations to, but that isn't very appropriate in this case because it's not a linear thing - the clicks could happen anytime. So the playhead on the timeline reaches the end of the first animation, and then when you place a new one at the end (much later, when someone clicks), the playhead would already be way past that spot where you're placing it, causing it to jump to the end on the next render (appropriately). It's cleaner to simply use a TweenMax here instead. Or you could create a new TimelineLite each time there's a click (don't worry - it's fast).

--

```
TweenMax.to(el, 0.5, {
  x: 150,
  autoAlpha: 0,
  scale: 0.5,
  onComplete: done
});
```

If you have any more questions, don't hesitate to swing by the GreenSock forums. https://greensock.com/forums/ where there's a great community focused on helping people with GSAP questions.

Happy tweening!